# Using variables inside function R. Error in is_data_pronoun(expr)

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I have created a function in R and have been using it in research for well over a month now. This function I have created takes use of the embrace operator {{. The purpose of the function isn't really important, but basically at the beginning of my function I created a tibble from the data given in which I use through the function.

```
f <- function(data, x, y, z){
  tb <- data %>% 
    transmute("var1" = {{x}},
              "var2" = {{y}},
              "var3" = {{z}})

# Do some stuff with tb

  return(tb)
}
```

My data lets call df already has the variable names x, y, and z so I have been able to just use function by just putting in the data name as shown below.

```
df <- tibble("x" = 1:3, 
             "y" = 4:6,
             "z" = 7:9)

f(data = df)
> output
```

However, today I installed tidymodels and right after I installed it I have been getting an error.

```
f(data = df)
>Error in is_data_pronoun(expr) : 
  argument "expr" is missing, with no default
```

It seems to fix this error all I have to do is give the variables names in the function and it works as show below.

```
f(data = df, x = x, y = y, z = z)
># A tibble: 3 x 3
   var1  var2  var3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     7
2     2     5     8
3     3     6     9
```

This is kinda annoying as now I would have to go all throughout my file when I use the function and put x = x, y = y, z = z in the function. Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error and why it all the sudden as come up and how to fix it? I am planning on publishing the function for others to use so thats why I'm using the {{. I have also already completely uninstalled R and all my packages and reinstalled what I was using except for tidymodels and am still getting the error. My guess is it has something to do with updated version of dplyr?

Here is my session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tseries_0.10-50            knitr_1.38                
 [3] tidyquant_1.0.3            quantmod_0.4.18           
 [5] TTR_0.24.3                 PerformanceAnalytics_2.0.4
 [7] xts_0.12.1                 zoo_1.8-9                 
 [9] lubridate_1.8.0            forecast_8.16             
[11] timetk_2.8.0               forcats_0.5.1             
[13] stringr_1.4.0              dplyr_1.0.8               
[15] purrr_0.3.4                readr_2.1.2               
[17] tidyr_1.2.0                tibble_3.1.6              
[19] ggplot2_3.3.5              tidyverse_1.3.1           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_2.0-3   ggsignif_0.6.3     ellipsis_0.3.2     class_7.3-20      
 [5] fs_1.5.2           rstudioapi_0.13    ggpubr_0.4.0       listenv_0.8.0     
 [9] furrr_0.2.3        prodlim_2019.11.13 fansi_1.0.3        xml2_1.3.3        
[13] codetools_0.2-18   splines_4.1.3      jsonlite_1.8.0     broom_0.7.12      
[17] dbplyr_2.1.1       compiler_4.1.3     httr_1.4.2         backports_1.4.1   
[21] assertthat_0.2.1   Matrix_1.4-0       fastmap_1.1.0      cli_3.2.0         
[25] htmltools_0.5.2    tools_4.1.3        gtable_0.3.0       glue_1.6.2        
[29] Rcpp_1.0.8.3       carData_3.0-5      cellranger_1.1.0   fracdiff_1.5-1    
[33] vctrs_0.4.0        urca_1.3-0         nlme_3.1-155       lmtest_0.9-40     
[37] timeDate_3043.102  gower_1.0.0        xfun_0.30          globals_0.14.0    
[41] rvest_1.0.2        lifecycle_1.0.1    rstatix_0.7.0      future_1.24.0     
[45] MASS_7.3-55        scales_1.1.1       ipred_0.9-12       hms_1.1.1         
[49] parallel_4.1.3     yaml_2.3.5         curl_4.3.2         rpart_4.1.16      
[53] stringi_1.7.6      hardhat_0.2.0      lava_1.6.10        rlang_1.0.2       
[57] pkgconfig_2.0.3    rsample_0.1.1      evaluate_0.15      lattice_0.20-45   
[61] recipes_0.2.0      tidyselect_1.1.2   parallelly_1.31.0  magrittr_2.0.3    
[65] R6_2.5.1           generics_0.1.2     DBI_1.1.2          pillar_1.7.0      
[69] haven_2.4.3        withr_2.5.0        survival_3.2-13    abind_1.4-5       
[73] nnet_7.3-17        future.apply_1.8.1 modelr_0.1.8       crayon_1.5.1      
[77] car_3.0-12         Quandl_2.11.0      utf8_1.2.2         tzdb_0.3.0        
[81] rmarkdown_2.13     grid_4.1.3         readxl_1.4.0       reprex_2.0.1      
[85] digest_0.6.29      munsell_0.5.0      quadprog_1.5-8
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior. I'm surprised it used to work at all. Did you have default function values for `x`, `y` and `z` specified? Are you sure it wasn't something like `f <- function(data, x=x, y=y, z=z){ ... }`? Otherwise those variables should be missing values. Maybe it was different in an older version of `rlang`? Can you include the output of `sessionInfo()` so we can see the version numbers of all the packages involved? Is there anywhere the old way works where you can grab the old version numbers as well?

Comment: I updated the post to include my session. But I think you are right it having something to do with rlang. I forgot it made me update rlang as well when installing tidymodels. The function never include ```function( x = x, y = y, z = z){}```. So I'm not sure why it worked in the past either. However I just updated the function to include ```x = x, y = y, z = z``` as default so i dont have to change it throughout my file.